# Why ets() function in R is not fitting a seasonal model?

Tags: r, forecasting

I am using `ets()` function in R to fit the seasonal model.I have a weekly sales data.I can see clearly in my data that it has seasonal patterns along with trend. Following is the code:

`x_ts<-ts(x,frequency=52,start=c(1,1))`

`nfit <- ets(x_ts,damped=FALSE)`

Is it because I have used damped=FALSE in my model?
I would appreciate any kind of help/suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read the warning message provided:

```
> x_ts <- ts(x,frequency=52,start=c(1,1))
> nfit <- ets(x_ts,damped=FALSE)

Warning message:
In ets(x_ts, damped = FALSE) :
  I can't handle data with frequency greater than 24. Seasonality 
  will be ignored. Try stlf() if you need seasonal forecasts.
```

Comment: Hello Mr. Hyndman.


I have weekly data that has a clear seasonality. Normally I use Python, but I am switching to R specifically for a project to use the fpp2, specifically for calculating confidence intervals. I have weekly data with strong seasonality.


Is there a walk around to handle weekly data with seasonality with ets()?


Thank you.
@Rob Hyndman

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation you can see the arguments passed: `ets(y, model="ZZZ", damped=NULL, alpha=NULL, beta=NULL, gamma=NULL, phi=NULL, ...)` and if you look further you read that model is usually a three-character string identifying the method, the first letter denotes the error type ("A", "M" or "Z"); the second letter denotes the trend type ("N","A","M" or "Z"); and the third letter denotes the season type ("N","A","M" or "Z"). In all cases, "N"=none, "A"=additive, "M"=multiplicative and "Z"=automatically selected.  You are not specifying the model type (by default it's all 'Z') and so the automated detection method is not picking up on the seasonal trend.  If you want to coerce it in, try "AAA" or "MAM".